# How can we change ActiveUser Identity in Mobilefirst 7.1.0

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-studio

Just after login we call an adapter to set active user identity. This adapter 
    has the following line of code:

```
WL.Server.setActiveUser(myrealm, null);
WL.Server.setActiveUser(myrealm,{displayName: param, userId:"abcd",
attributes:{'firstname':"aaaa"}});
var gact = WL.Server.getActiveUser(myrealm);

return gact;
```

it gives the following error:

[ERROR] FWLSE0243E: Unable to set the active user for realm 'xx'. The 
supplied userIdentity is not accepted by the login module.
[ERROR ] FWLSE0035E: Invocation of procedure 'X' failed.
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0209E: Writer already obtained

Need advice? How to solve this issue? We want to set some userIdentity until the user is logged in.

Comment: This approach works for Adapterbased authentication. The error messages you see do not happen when setting identity as shown. Are you using this with another authentication mechanism - like custom login module?

Comment: Thanks Vivin, yes we are using it for FormBased Authentication not adapter based. getActiveUser returns correct login UserID but if we want to set some attributes before , we received these errors.